# Ошибка php в терминале

Tags: php, laravel, docker, artisan

У меня запущен docker на winde и в принципе изначально все работало. Но сегодня попытался выполнить команду php artisan и упало этор  "php" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом. Подозреваю что проблема в переменных среды. Тогда вопрос что мне туда вписать или проблема в другом?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8088:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.23
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "4306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: apply
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 24867
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 24867
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

проблема в переменной среды, был указан не верный путь к bin php